# Fortran warning for data type

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings, equation, linear-equation

I wrote the main program for a subroutine that solves a set of equations (Thomas algorithm) in Fortran. This is the code for a simple set of equations:

```
Program Thomas
implicit none
integer i
integer,parameter :: n=2

real,dimension(n) :: a,b,c,d,x

a(1)=0
a(2)=0
b(1)=1
b(2)=2
c(1)=0
c(2)=0
d(1)=5
d(2)=10

call solve_tridiag(a,b,c,d,x,n)

do i = n-1, 1, -1
  print*, x(i)
end do

end program

subroutine solve_tridiag(a,b,c,d,x,n)
  implicit none
!    a - sub-diagonal (means it is the diagonal below the main diagonal)
!    b - the main diagonal
!    c - sup-diagonal (means it is the diagonal above the main diagonal)
!    d - right part
!    x - the answer
!    n - number of equations

    integer,parameter :: r8 = kind(1.d0)

    integer,intent(in) :: n
    real(r8),dimension(n),intent(in) :: a,b,c,d
    real(r8),dimension(n),intent(out) :: x
    real(r8),dimension(n) :: cp,dp
    real(r8) :: m
    integer i

    ! initialize c-prime and d-prime
    cp(1) = c(1)/b(1)
    dp(1) = d(1)/b(1)
 ! solve for vectors c-prime and d-prime
     do i = 2,n
       m = b(i)-cp(i-1)*a(i)
       cp(i) = c(i)/m
       dp(i) = (d(i)-dp(i-1)*a(i))/m
     end do
 ! initialize x
     x(n) = dp(n)
 ! solve for x from the vectors c-prime and d-prime
    do i = n-1, 1, -1
      x(i) = dp(i)-cp(i)*x(i+1)
    end do

   end subroutine solve_tridiag
```

When I compile the program I get this warning:

```
warning FOR4227: argument A (number 1) in reference to procedure SOLVE_TRIDIAG from procedure THOMAS incorrect: has the wrong data type

warning FOR4227: argument B (number 2) in reference to procedure SOLVE_TRIDIAG from procedure THOMAS incorrect: has the wrong data type

warning FOR4227: argument C (number 3) in reference to procedure SOLVE_TRIDIAG from procedure THOMAS incorrect: has the wrong data type

warning FOR4227: argument D (number 4) in reference to procedure SOLVE_TRIDIAG from procedure THOMAS incorrect: has the wrong data type

warning FOR4227: argument X (number 5) in reference to procedure SOLVE_TRIDIAG from procedure THOMAS incorrect: has the wrong data type
```

And when I run it I face a run-time error. What is wrong with the data type? and what is the reason for the run-time error?

Comment: Quick guess `real` versus `real(r8)`.

Comment: @albert is right. You are passing a default kind real to a real with kind r8, and they are different things. If you had an interface in scope at the calling point, which has been good practice since 1990, the code would fail to compile, an even better indicator of a problem.